# How to automatically synchronise/save bookmarked websites to Pocket or Instapaper?

Tags: bookmarks, instapaper, pocket

I would like to be able to access my bookmarked websites when I am working without an internet connection. Aside this background, is it possible to automatize the process of saving by bookmarked website to either Pocket or Instapaper to have them accessible offline?

The ideal solution would be that every newly bookmarked website―but also all existing bookmarks―are automatically synchronised with Instapaper or Pocket.

Comment: you need to be online to access Instapaper - how do you plan to access content from Instapaper, unless you're using an app to sync content to somewhere else?

Comment: Also, there's no online "hook" that would be able to fire an IFTTT action. This, unfortunately, doesn't seem possible to me. Why not just save the site to Pocket directly? There are tools to do that.

Comment: @Sathya Instapaper doesn't have an offline mode similar to the Pocket Chrome app?

Comment: @al-e I can save future websites directly to Pocket but I was hoping to find a way to save all my existing bookmarks directly into Pocket.

Comment: Pocket has a Delicious importer. If you get your bookmarks into Delicious and export them (or just get a file in the right format) you can bulk import them at https://getpocket.com/import/delicious

Comment: @AlE. That was a useful hint through which I found a solution: https://getpocket.com/import/browser

Answer (score 2):

Bookmarks cannot be automatically synchronised to Pocket. However, existing browser bookmarks can be periodically imported by the user in a manual fashion using the Pocket [Import Browser Bookmarks](https://getpocket.com/import/browser) tool. (The page also offers instructions for exporting bookmarks from Chrome, Firefox, and Safari.)

As of now, Instapaper does not offer any option to import browser bookmarks.